# Disable Power/Reset button temporarily on Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7

I'm looking for some C# code or tool to that allows to disable the power and reset button on a desktop PC.

This is to prevent toddler's from pressing the tower reset/power button.

I'm using this program ([Toddler Keys](http://tk.ms11.net/)) right now to disable drive doors but unfortunately, the power option only works in XP

**Update**

I found [ShutdownGuard](http://code.google.com/p/shutdownguard/) which is close to the task.

Comment: Control Panel's Power Options have a setting to handle what happens when the Power/Sleep buttons are pressed with the option of specifying "Do Nothing". However, I think you are out of luck if someone does a long press on the power butotn.

Comment: I need something to quickly toggle. After I login, I want the option to 'DO nothing" but then when **I** want to shutdown, I should be able to. This is why I haven't taken off the wire from mobo.

Comment: Yes so what I am telling you is that there should be an API call to do just that :) Also if the power options worked in XP, there should be an API call to do that in Windows 7 as well.

Comment: And that is what I'm asking for here! :)

Comment: Take a look at this article. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463247.aspx. It says something about **Using Power Management APIs from Managed Code**... and also this article where some one is trying to do I think exactly what you want http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/6d275fad-bca0-429f-9adf-cf67d4ecd68e

Comment: @RanhiruCooray: you should really post this as an answer so you can be credited...

Comment: You could invoke the naughty step every time this happens, get an office door, or save the computer till after bed time. If the power switch is not available to get your attention, what will be next? If the switch is getting pressed when you are not using the computer then you have a budding geek.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution for a tower is hardware - a piece of plexiglass in front of the tower, for example. Depending on your toddler and the supervision level you provide, you could just prop it in front, or velcro it in place. If the tower is on a shelf, attaching the plexiglass to the shelf is even better.

Comment: Tried that already!  He's too smart for that now. He takes it off, presses it and replaces it back ;)

Comment: Hm, sounds like a job for either height (top of a bookcase screwed to the wall) or guile (those desks with a door for putting the machine in, and a child proof lock on the door.) Still an advocate for hardware solutions over software, since you also need to deal with plugs being pulled from the wall etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is two non coding solution: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/topic117236.html

1. Pull the cable from the switch ;)
2. Change the setting in the windows power options (look in the link for details).

Comment: #1 is a pain as you cannot start your computer after a power off. #2 will work but I want a shortcut to do that and not have to wade thru all those screens/options every time *I* need to shut it down. I'm using [ShutdownGuard](http://code.google.com/p/shutdownguard/) right now as a compromise.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be out of luck with software solutions to this as reset and long-press power is handled by the motherboard. You'd be best off removing the buttons from their connections on the motherboard and replacing them your own buttons that you can put out of reach.

Comment: I'm not quite sure you get exactly what I mean, I meant make a small box with 2 pushbuttons that you can put out of reach with long wires to the motherboard connectors to power and reset, replacing the connections for the case buttons - then you get to keep the power and reset buttons but are able to locate them out of reach.

Comment: Oh I missed the last part of your comment, Yeah that would work too!